# How can I reduce the size of the video sent using twilio so that it works reliably in low bandwidths too?

Tags: video, video-streaming, twilio

I am using twilio for a video chat application. I would like to see the video size to the lowest possible so that the video chat works in the lowest possible bandwidth. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using the Android, iOS or JavaScript SDKs for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set the bit rate for twilio video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636803/is-it-possible-to-set-the-bit-rate-for-twilio-video)