# Is it possible to set the bit rate for twilio video?

Tags: video, twilio, twilio-api

I am developing a video chat application with twilio-video. I observed that the video chat gets stuck in low bandwidths. Is it possible to set the bitrate for the video so that the video chat works in low bandwidths too?

The documentation says that twilio will automatically rescale the video to make it work in low bandwidths. But in my experience, this hasnt been the case. How can I ensure that the chat works fine in low bandwidths?

```
 var connectOptions = {
                name: roomName,
                logLevel: 'debug',
                tracks: mediaStream.getTracks(),
                maxAudioBitrate: 16000,
                maxVideoBitrate: 64000,
            };
            return Video.connect(data.token, connectOptions);
```

This is where I am setting maxVideoBitrate.

twilio version is 3.6.7
twilio-video version is 1.0.0

And the codecname, according to googCodecName is VP8. codecImplementationName   is libvpx.

Comment: Are you using the Android, iOS or JavaScript SDKs for this?

Comment: Javascript SDK. I am setting the maxVideoBitrate as 64000. But setting this seems to have no change in the quality. Can I somehow check the bitrate of the video sent?

Comment: I checked using chrome://webrtc-internals/ and can confirm that setting maxVideoBitrate seem to have no effect in the bitrate shown there. To be precise, I was getting bitrates well over 120k even when the maxBitrate was set to 64k. Why is this?

Comment: Ok, can you share the code you are using to try to constrain the bitrates? Also, which version of the Video SDK are you using? And can you tell the codec that's being used from the webrtc internals too? Thanks

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio Video does support setting the maximum bitrate for video and audio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/09/safari-11-support-for-programmable-video-and-more.html), however it was not part of the initial version 1.0.0 release.

Support for setting `maxVideoBitrate` and `maxAudioBitrate` was [released in version 1.3.0](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-4). I recommend upgrading to at least version 1.3.0, if not to the latest 1.6.0.

Let me know if that helps.